# Failed to build Android project with Google Play services

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm in the process of incorporating Google sign-in into my app, but I'm getting errors in Android Studio when trying to build the project. I'm including `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'` as a dependency in my app-level gradle file and `'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'` as a dependency in my project-level gradle file. Building the project gives me the error: `Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.2` with an option to "Install Repository and sync project", but clicking this option does nothing. I have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of the app-level gradle file. There are no other instances where I'm using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-*` dependencies. I have "Google Play services" installed via the SDK Manager. Any help would be appreciated and I can provide more information as needed.

Comment: lol, google play services library is just on 9.0.1, maybe that is your problem, your are trying to use 9.0.2
and when you submit this post, was on version 9.0.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I updated the project-level build.gradle to

```
'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and it worked for me. Hope that helps!

Comment: this one is a really old version of Google Services. If you will try to use new functionalities, just will not work.

Comment: I don't think google-services 3.0.0 is old, it looks to me to be the latest one. Are you maybe referring to google-play-services (which is up to 9.2.0 right now)?

Answer (score 0):

For me its asking to download one repository I have downloaded that and then sync again it worked for me.